# Finding a subset minimizing distance of the mean from a specific point.

Tags: optimization, algorithms, computational-complexity, computational-mathematics, discrete-optimization

Let $X := \{x_1, x_2,..., x_n\} \subset \mathbb{R}$, $d\in \mathbb{R}$, $k \in \mathbb{N}$. I am interested in the following optimization problem

$$\min_{A \subseteq X, |A|=k} \left|\sum_{x_i\in A}\frac{x_i}{k}-d\right|.$$

In other words, I want to find such a subset $A \subset X$ having $k$ points for which the distance between the mean and $d$ is minimal. Numbers $k$ and $d$  are given.

Are there any (efficient) algorithms for finding $A$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can solve the problem via integer linear programming as follows.  For $x_i \in X$, let binary decision variable $y_i$ indicate whether $x_i \in A$.  Let $z$ be a nonnegative variable that represents the absolute value.  The problem is to minimize $z$ subject to linear constraints
\begin{align}
\sum_{x_i \in X} y_i &= k \tag1\\
\sum_{x_i \in X} \frac{x_i}{k} y_i - d &\le z \tag2\\
\sum_{x_i \in X} \frac{x_i}{k} y_i - d &\ge -z \tag3
\end{align}
Constraint $(1)$ enforces $|A|=k$.  Constraints $(2)$ and $(3)$ linearize the absolute value.