# Minimizing distance of the mean from a point

Tags: optimization, algorithms, computational-complexity, nonlinear-optimization, discrete-optimization

This is similar to [this question.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4403447/finding-a-subset-minimizing-distance-of-the-mean-from-a-specific-point)

Let $X := \{x_1, x_2,..., x_n\} \subset \mathbb{R}$, $d\in \mathbb{R}$. I am interested in the following optimization problem

$$\min_{A \subseteq X} \left|\sum_{x_i\in A}\frac{x_i}{|A|}-d\right|,$$

i.e. finding a subset of $A$ which minimizes the distance of the mean from $d$.

Please note that right now I do not specify number of points in $A$ and it seems to me that it cannot be re-expressed as a linear programming problem.

Is there any efficient way to solve this problem?

Comment: The introduction of $k$ makes the description confusing.  You list it along with $X$ and $d$ as if it were part of the input, but the rest of your question indicates that $k$ is not fixed.  I think you should just replace $k$ with $|A|$ in the objective function.

Comment: @RobPratt, thanks, indeed it might be confusing. I edited the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As in my answer to the linked question, let binary decision variable $y_i$ indicate whether $x_i \in A$.  You want to minimize
$$\left|\frac{\sum\limits_{x_i \in X} x_i y_i}{\sum\limits_{x_i \in X} y_i} - d\right|.$$
Let $z$ be a nonnegative variable that represents the absolute value.  The problem is to minimize $z$ subject to constraints
\begin{align}
\frac{\sum\limits_{x_i \in X} x_i y_i}{\sum\limits_{x_i \in X} y_i} - d &\le z \tag1\\
\frac{\sum\limits_{x_i \in X} x_i y_i}{\sum\limits_{x_i \in X} y_i} - d &\ge -z \tag2
\end{align}
Equivalently (because $\sum_i y_i > 0$),
\begin{align}
\sum_{x_i \in X} (x_i - d) y_i &\le z \sum_{x_i \in X} y_i \tag3\label3\\
\sum_{x_i \in X} (x_i - d) y_i &\ge -z \sum_{x_i \in X} y_i \tag4\label4
\end{align}
The LHS of constraints \eqref{3} and \eqref{4} is linear.  It remains to linearize the RHS.  Introduce decision variable $w_i$ to represent the product $z y_i$.  Assuming $0 \le z \le M$, the following linear constraints do the job:
\begin{align}
0\le w_i &\le M y_i &&\text{for all $i$} \tag5\label{5} \\
-M (1-y_i) \le w_i - z &\le 0 &&\text{for all $i$} \tag6\label{6} \\
\end{align}
Constraint \eqref{5} enforces $y_i = 0 \implies w_i = 0$.
Constraint \eqref{6} enforces $y_i = 1 \implies w_i = z$.
Now rewrite \eqref{3} and \eqref{4} as
\begin{align}
\sum_{x_i \in X} (x_i - d) y_i &\le  \sum_{x_i \in X} w_i \tag7\label7\\
\sum_{x_i \in X} (x_i - d) y_i &\ge -\sum_{x_i \in X} w_i \tag8\label8
\end{align}

In summary, a linear formulation is to minimize $z$ subject to \eqref{5} through \eqref{8}.

Comment: Very nice! +1 — creative solve for RHS

Answer (score 0):

I might be missing something, but isn't the method used in the answer from your link still usable in this scenario after we drop constraint $(1)$?

Comment: I don't think so - $k$ is not fixed (please see RobPratt's comment under my question).